# Why do natural speakers of (predominantly) Indian languages use "the same"

Tags: english

I've noticed that a lot of people who first speak an "Indian" language (I don't know which languages specifically, but from that region) then learn English perhaps as an adult use "the same" to avoid repeating themselves, whereas I, an American English speaker, would use "it."

As an example, I recently interacted with a person who said

> ... looks like i mixed up between different versions of schema definition. I am correcting **the same** and will update **the same** here.

I'm curious what constructs, idioms, etc., may exist in those other languages that would lead so many people to use this phrase.